# Nav bar displays text in simulator but not storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the nav bar transparent with only the bar button being displayed in my app. In my storyboard I have no title so that the nav bar looks like nothing is there, but when I run the simulator, the text that I deleted is in the nav bar.

This is what i've found to solve problem:

**What the nav bar should look like without the transparency**

[image: What the nav bar should look like without the transparency (in Storyboard)]

**What the nav bar looks like in the simulator**

[image: What the nav bar looks like in the simulator]

My code for making the bar transparent:

```
//Makes navigation bar translucent        
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

In your code, inside view will appear method 
use this code

```
self.title = "" // or whatever text you have
```

In your app delegate, did finish launching with option method:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = 
    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]  // shouldn't be needed, but if you want something
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .blue
```

From your storybord remove any changes done by you. It can be done from code, also since it needs to be consistent in the app. Try to handle status bar and navigation bar from code itself.

Comment: I editted it to .clear and comment my code. It doesn't make the nav bar transparent like I wanted.